# Using \n from user input to make new line

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making command in my bot to send embed with specified parameters (like: title, description...), and I want my bot to recognize \n in user input as new line function (not just "\n" text).

This is how command input looks like:

[image: command input]

And this is how command output looks like:

[image: command output]

How command output should look like:

> line1
>
> line2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will be safer for your application to just manually replace them in content. You can simply use [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method:

```js
const processedDescription = originalDescription.replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
```

Also, as additional note: it might be much comfortable to use Discord Modals for embeds instead of command arguments. You can checkout how to use them (if you're using discord.js) [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/modals.html#modals).